# Clash of clans switching accounts in one device

Tags: ios, apple-id, game-center, clash-of-clans

I want to to make another clash of clans base but when I log out of Game Center and log into another account it doesn't ask if I want to delete my base and sign in with the new Game Center. Is there any other was i can get a new base with out loosing my old one?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the game. If that doesn't work, sign out of Game Center, delete the app, reinstall it, and you should have a new base. Then, when you sign back in with game center, it should ask if you want to merge the bases.